# repairing damage to coating on stainless steel fridge

Tags: steel, stainless

Ok people, I really screwed up. We recently bought a floor display fridge from Lowes.  Because it was a floor display it didn't come with a box.  Delivery staff taped the doors with packaging tape, which was nearly impossible to remove completely.  I didn't want to use any sharp object for obvious reasons.  I thought I could maybe get the remaining tape off by softening it with some acetone, because I thought stainless steel is pretty impervious.  Well it turned out that it had some sort of finish on it that prevents finger prints.   The acetone dissolved it and now I have a bunch of streaks on a brand new fridge.

Question is:  Is there a way to repair this? What is the process.  Or do we just cover it with children's artwork?

[image: PIC OF FRIDGE]

Comment: Children's artwork is what fridges are for, isn't it?

Comment: White contact paper and you have a DIY fridge whiteboard

Comment: My fridge doors are smooth and white (the sides, sadly, are "pebble" or "alligator" texture) - it is a very nice whiteboard right out of the gate.

Comment: I would consult the factory.

Comment: You're probably gonna need to use tape for your artwork, because magnets don't work on most stainless steel!

Comment: @Huesmann I've had plenty of "stainless steel" fridges and magnets stick to them all just fine. IDK if they use variant that's actually ferrous, if there's actually a plain steel layer underneath the stainless surface, or something else, but magnets have always stuck.

Comment: A bit late, but: Always test a solvent or cleaner or colorant on an inconspicuous corner before applying it more broadly, to make sure you know what to expect from it.

Answer (score 4):

For future reference, start with things milder than acetone, when whipping out the solvents.

I suspect you might be able to take something like white or gray scotchbrite pads (finer abrasive than the green ones) to it and polish it back to bare "brushed" metal, but unless you do the whole thing that probably will look different form the "no-fingerprint" coated sections. And, I suppose, take fingerprints.

Comment: YES, in retrospect I should have started with soap and hot water, then maybe denatured alcohol.   I just didn't know that there was a coating on the SS, I stupidly thought it was all just "naked" SS.   Thanks for everyone's comments.

Comment: Most likely, the die was cast when they stuck shipping tape to it, if that's really a clearcoat over the stainless.

Comment: I think at this point you might as well take acetone to the rest of the door, get all the coating off, and deal with the fingerprints!